# How to get array values from the string in PHP?

Tags: php, arrays

I have a sting, In that string, my array values are stored. How can I get array value from the string? Is there any predefined function in PHP or will achieve using REGEX?

```
$rule ="array(
array('parameter'=> 'signature name', 'values'=>'RNSOC023', 'condition'=>'EQUALS', 'rule type'=>'AND'),
array('parameter'=> 'DestinationZone', 'values'=>'l3-internet', 'condition'=>'EQUALS', 'rule type'=>'AND'),
array('parameter'=> 'Application', 'values'=>'ftp,sftp', 'condition'=>'EQUALS', 'rule type'=>'AND')
)";
```

if I do print_r($rule); it's giving string value only same as above. But I want output like

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [parameter] => signature name [values] => RNSOC023 [condition] => EQUALS [rule type] => AND ) [1] => Array ( [parameter] => DestinationZone [values] => l3-internet [condition] => EQUALS [rule type] => AND ) [2] => Array ( [parameter] => Application [values] => ftp,sftp [condition] => EQUALS [rule type] => AND ) )
```

Comment: you theoretical could use the evil `eval`. But before going that direction: Where is the string coming from?

Comment: That are rules defined by machine and stored as a string in db

Comment: Then you would have to eval it. But I owuld suggest you definitely change the way it is stored. Store it as JSON or serialized, because that can be easily hydrated to the original type (so an array).

Comment: Just remove the string delimeter `"` from $rule value.

Comment: If the values stored in db won't change anymore I suggest to run a 'converting' script once to get usable values into your db. If that 'machine' keeps updating/adding to db and you cannot change that - eval is the left over choice. Maybe think about suing the 'developer' who made the machine do that...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally got the solution, Try this:

```
$rule ="array(
    array('parameter'=> 'signature name', 'values'=>'RNSOC023', 'condition'=>'EQUALS', 'rule type'=>'AND'),
    array('parameter'=> 'DestinationZone', 'values'=>'l3-internet', 'condition'=>'EQUALS', 'rule type'=>'AND'),
    array('parameter'=> 'Application', 'values'=>'ftp,sftp', 'condition'=>'EQUALS', 'rule type'=>'AND')
    )";
    $returnValue = '';
    eval("\$returnValue = $rule;");
    print_r($returnValue);
```

Comment: have you tried it?? Results in `array(1) { [0]=> string(324) "array( array('parameter'=>...`

Comment: Again remain content getting string only

Answer (score 3):

eval() is EVIL! It renders your code open to all sorts of security issues and should be avoided at all costs. Try this instead:

```
$rule ="array(
array('parameter'=> 'signature name', 'values'=>'RNSOC023', 'condition'=>'EQUALS', 'rule type'=>'AND'),
array('parameter'=> 'DestinationZone', 'values'=>'l3-internet', 'condition'=>'EQUALS', 'rule type'=>'AND'),
array('parameter'=> 'Application', 'values'=>'ftp,sftp', 'condition'=>'EQUALS', 'rule type'=>'AND')
)";
preg_match_all("/(?:array\()('.*?'\s*=>\s*'.*?'\s*)+(?:\))/", $rule, $matches);
$rulearray = array();
$i = 0;
foreach ($matches[1] as $value) {
    preg_match_all("/('.*?'\s*=>\s*'.*?')/", $value, $m);
    foreach ($m[1] as $e) {
        list ($k, $v) = preg_split('/\s*=>\s*/', $e);
        $rulearray[$i][$k] = $v;
    }
    $i++;
}
print_r($rulearray);
```

Output:

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( ['parameter'] => 'signature name'
                       ['values'] => 'RNSOC023'
                       ['condition'] => 'EQUALS'
                       ['rule type'] => 'AND' ) 
        [1] => Array ( ['parameter'] => 'DestinationZone' 
                       ['values'] => 'l3-internet' 
                       ['condition'] => 'EQUALS'
                       ['rule type'] => 'AND' ) 
        [2] => Array ( ['parameter'] => 'Application'
                       ['values'] => 'ftp,sftp'
                       ['condition'] => 'EQUALS'
                       ['rule type'] => 'AND' )
)
```

Comment: thanks dude, just learnt a new way to keep an array in string format <3

Answer (score 0):

The code will be executed in the scope of the code calling eval(). Thus any variables defined or changed in the eval() call will remain visible after it terminates. For More Info [HERE](http://php.net/manual/en/function.eval.php)

```
eval("\$rule = $rule;");
print_r($rule);
```

Answer (score 0):

The approach you are using to keep array of data in a database is wrong, You should use json string format in the database and when getting data, you can json_decode function in php to convert into array. Try to convert that array into json string and store in the db. It's the best practise. That's why you are getting these types of issues.

Comment: Agree, But in my scenario, I have to do like this only

Comment: why? where is the place that you are going to save array ? Or is it existing from beginning ?

Answer (score 0):

So basically you would want json_encode() to make the array.
What I tested now was the following:

```
$rule = array(array('parameter1'=> 'signature name', 'values'=>'RNSOC023', 'condition'=>'EQUALS', 'rule type'=>'AND'), 1 => array('parameter2'=> 'DestinationZone', 'values'=>'l3-internet', 'condition'=>'EQUALS', 'rule type'=>'AND'), 2 => array('parameter'=> 'Application', 'values'=>'ftp,sftp', 'condition'=>'EQUALS', 'rule type'=>'AND'));
$jr = json_encode($rule);
$jd = json_decode($jr, true);
print $jd[0]['values'];
```

The above worked, and tested on my environment.

For more information on [`json_encode();`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) and [`json_decode();`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php)

If you run `print_r($jd);` you will get an output of:

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [parameter1] => signature name [values] => RNSOC023 [condition] => EQUALS [rule type] => AND ) [1] => Array ( [parameter2] => DestinationZone [values] => l3-internet [condition] => EQUALS [rule type] => AND ) [2] => Array ( [parameter] => Application [values] => ftp,sftp [condition] => EQUALS [rule type] => AND ) )
```

Comment: You have to take in the string. you removed the quotations